# Gazebo's Fuerte Dependencies Causing Groovy Issues

Tags: groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using ROS Groovy but have Gazebo 1.3 and its Fuerte dependencies installed as well. I believe the urdfdom package is having issues because of having both the Fuerte and Groovy versions installed. It is throwing errors such as:

> ERROR ros.rosconsole_bridge.console_bridge: Material [Brown] color has no rgba
> ERROR ros.rosconsole_bridge.console_bridge: Material [Brown] not defined in file

But when I remove Gazebo and Fuerte dependencies, this error goes away.

When can we expect a stand alone version of Gazebo that depends on Groovy instead? Thanks!

[Original, Related Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/52391/roscd-only-finding-rosbuild-packages/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/855/gazebo%27s-fuerte-dependencies-causing-groovy-issues/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This has been solved thanks to your hard work Dave. Gazebo can be used with ROS groovy using `gazebo_ros_pkgs`, which [has documentation provided by Dave](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-23**:
go intern me!